# cakedc csvimport fetches no record from csv file

Tags: excel, cakephp, csv, cakedc

I have the following CSV file, the first line is the header:

```
admission_no;first_name;last_name;gender;date_of_birth;join_date;form_id;stream_id;school_photo
1003;"cavin";"cavin";"cavin";"male";1992-11-02;2007-01-25;1;1
1004;"joshua";"joshua";"joshua";"male";1992-11-03;2007-01-26;1;1
1005;"elijah";"elijah";"elijah";"male";1992-11-04;2007-01-27;1;1
1006;"lawrent";"lawrent";"lawrent";"male";1992-11-05;2007-01-28;1;1
1007;"steven";"steven";"steven";"male";1992-11-06;2007-01-29;1;2
1008;"javan";"javan";"javan";"male";1992-11-07;2007-01-30;1;2
1009;"miller";"miller";"miller";"male";1992-11-08;2007-01-31;1;2
1010;"javis";"javis";"javis";"male";1992-11-09;2007-02-01;1;2
1011;"fredrick";"fredrick";"fredrick";"male";1992-11-10;2007-02-02;1;3
1012;"fredrick";"fredrick";"fredrick";"male";1992-11-11;2007-02-03;1;3
1013;"nahashon";"nahashon";"nahashon";"male";1992-11-12;2007-02-04;1;3
1014;"nelson";"nelson";"nelson";"male";1992-11-13;2007-02-05;1;3
1015;"martin";"martin";"martin";"male";1992-11-14;2007-02-06;1;4
1016;"felix";"felix";"fwlix";"male";1992-11-15;2007-02-07;1;4
1017;"tobias";"tobias";"tobias";"male";1992-11-16;2007-02-08;1;4
1018;"dennis";"dennis";"dennis";"male";1992-11-17;2007-02-09;1;4
1019;"bildad";"bildad";"bildad";"male";1992-11-18;2007-02-10;1;5
1020;"syslvester";"sylvester";"sylvester";"male";1992-11-19;2007-02-11;1;5
```

And my database table columns are: `admission_no`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `gender`, `date_of_birth`, `join_date`, `form_id`, `stream_id` and `school_photo`.

Using the CakeDC Utils plugin to import the data, I get a flash message:

> Successfully imported 0 records from file.csv

I have tried removing the header, changing the delimiter or even adding `NULL` for the `school_photo` column since it is nullable but nothing seems to work.

Can someone tell me what am doing wrong?

am generating the csv using Ubuntu libre Office 
the import function:

```
function import() {
   $modelClass = $this->modelClass;
   if( $this->request->is('POST') ) {
   $records_count = $this->$modelClass->find('count');
    try {
      $this->$modelClass->importCSV($this->request->data[$modelClass]['CsvFile']['tmp_name']);
    }catch (Exception $e) {
        $import_errors = $this->$modelClass->getImportErrors();
       $this->set('import_errors', $import_errors);
       $this->Session->setFlash(__('Error importing')."  ".$this->request->data[$modelClass]['CsvFile']['name']. ",". __('column mismatch'));
       $this->redirect(array('action' => 'import'));
    }
       $new_records_count = $this->$modelClass->find('count') - $records_count;
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Successfully imported')."  ". $new_records_count . "  ".'records from' . "  ".$this->request->data[$modelClass]['CsvFile']['name']);
            //$this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
  }
    $this->set('modelClass', $modelClass);
   $this->render('../Common/import');
```

}//end import

the view file

```
<h3>Import <?php echo Inflector::pluralize($modelClass); ?> from CSV data file</h3>
  <?php 
    echo $this->Form->create($modelClass, array('action' => 'import', 'type' => 'file'));
    echo $this->Form->input('CsvFile', array('label' => '', 'type' => 'file'));
    echo $this->Form->end('Submit');
```

?>

Answer (score -2):

Make sure your line endings are something your server can read.  I've been burned by this a million times... especially if using a mac to generate the CSV from Excel.  save as "csv for windows".

Background: OS X tends to save files with `\r` (carriage return) line endings, while Windows uses `\r\n` (carriage return, line feed). To make it worse all other Unix-like systems (e.g. Linux) tend to use only `\n`.
Thus if you save a file on OS X and the open it on Windows, Windows thinks the file is only one big line.

You can verify this with a good editor (a programming editor which can display whitespace as symbols) or by looking at the actual hex Code of the file.

Comment: Could you add some more details or code to help make your answer for understandable and comprehensive?

Comment: i have added the responsible codes and also to mention i generated teh csv file in ubuntu